# Feature-based grammars with semantic actions in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, ply

I would like to interpret a controlled language, in the sense of parsing it and taking actions. For parsing a language, I very much appreciate the simplicity and power of [NLTK feature-based grammars](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch09.html). But I don't know how to attach semantic actions to productions of NLTK feature-based grammars.

On the other hand, I used [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html) (Python Lex Yacc) to interpret a (relatively simple) controlled language, which allowed me to use states, semantic actions, and all bells and whistles provided by Lex and Yacc (which I cherish ever since the 80s). But these grammars are not feature-based.

Is there some way to combine the two worlds? Attach actions to NLTK grammars, or attach features to PLY grammars?